# Best practice for joining tables with case

Tags: sql, join, case

I need to join two different tables in two different situations. In this scenario I have to solve my problem with these two solutions;

1) I will create a statement(S.ShipmentType) to use in join like this:

```
SELECT  S.*, P.*

,CASE
    WHEN S.ShipmentType = 'import' THEN SP.SupplierName
    WHEN S.ShipmentType = 'export' THEN C.CustomerName
END AS ShipmentDesination

FROM            tblShippments   S 
INNER JOIN      tblProducts     P   ON S.productId = P.productID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblCustomers    C   ON S.companyId = C.customerId AND S.ShipmentType = 'export'
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblSuppliers    SP  ON S.companyId = SP.supplierId AND S.ShipmentType = 'import'
```

2) Or I will create two different shipments tables for imports and exports, then use two different queries to get data.

Which one is the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would do this with two separate queries, but I don't hate this solution either. I think it's both feasible.

Btw, I think you should be able to solve this without the `CASE WHEN`, assuming that CompanyId is unique over both tblCustomers and tblSuppliers. In that case you could simply do:

```
COALESCE(SP.SupplierName, C.CustomerName)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Unfortunately id numbers are possible to be same but even so COALESCE works because S.ShipmentType filter in join.
But about performance still I cannot imagine what kind of effects I will have.

Comment: Performance is pretty tricky in SQL, because it is declarative. It is dependant upon many things, like database implementation used, indices and amount of data in the tables. In general, for a simple query like this I wouldn't worry about performance unless we're talking millions of records.

Comment: Actually this example is not my problem, I wanted to write an understandable question. Right now I have 300.000 records in my table. But as you say it seems there is no big difference between two solutions.